# $http.post results in 404 error but only on local server

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http-status-code-404

I'm quite new to angular and so to make things easier, I used the Yeoman AngularJS Generator - which means I can use Grunt to initiate a local server and watch for changes in my files. My folder structure is as follows:

```
appFolder
| - node_modules
| - bower_components
| - test //for unit testing 
| - app //main app folder 
    | - images
    | - styles
    | - views
        | - includes // partial HTML's
    | - scripts 
        | - controllers
        | - services
        | - app.js
    | - feeds // this is the Database
        | - user-details 
            | - document.json // this is what I'm trying to get to
```

Inside one of my controllers, I have an `$http.post`:

```
$http.post('feeds/user-details/document.json', $scope.formInfo).
                success(function() {
                    console.log('posted');
                }).
                error(function() {
                    console.log('not posted');
                });
```

Doing the `$http.post` results in a 404 Error as per the network tab (from Chrome Dev Tools) with the Response: `Cannot POST /feeds/user-details/document.json`

The data to be posted are basic signup details: firstName, lastName, email: {"firstName":"first","lastName":"surname","email":"fsalaysay@gmail.com","password":"myPass"} - I have a `span` that reflects the value of `$scope.formInfo` on the page so I'm sure that's exactly what the data looks like.

Though when I do it using a RESTful api tester (in this case, I use http://rest.learncode.academy), it results in a success. I've tried researching on it and tried a lot of the methods on the web including using: `{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}` but to no avail.

What am I missing? Is there a piece of code I need to write so that I can write on the specified JSON document? Mind pointing me in the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you trying to post directly to a document, as in, are you trying to overwrite / append to the `document.json` file through the POST request above without having any underlying server code to handle it?

Comment: You need a server route to post to and server code that will write to your file. You can't post to a static resource file

Comment: @callmekatootie Yes that's what I'm trying to do. Any chance you can point me in the right direction (maybe a tutorial)?